# Vista professional 64 bit after complete the update there is no network connection

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, drivers

I have Vista Professional x64. I have installed it on a PC and a lot of updates have been applied and till yesterday morning everything were working fine. So I tried to install Internet explorer 9.  I installed 87 missing updates and after that I restarted and I had no network connection.  Each time if I put on DHCP it's working fine but if I have to set static IP it's working temporary which means just when I restart the PC the network doesn't work again

Note 1: In cmd when type ipconfig it show me a different IP 169.254.190.104 instead of 10.x.x.x but in network management on IPv4 it's 10.x.x.x so i'm not understand how with ipconfig IP it's 169.254.190.104 and in network management is another IP 10.x.x.x and I just have one ethernet card.

Note 2: I have tried to remove the driver and reinstalled again many times and stuck the same problems.

Note 3: Windows updates hasn't update my network card driver and model is Intel(R) 82562V 10/100 64 bit.